# Install Windows 7 over a Windows installed HDD SATA with box enclosure

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, windows-8

The SATA port on my Notebook (Aspire 5810T) is broken.

I went to a repair center to see about repairing but it was too expensive just for a try. Now I'm left with an HDD SATA 320GB and my Notebook.

I heard that using the "[box system](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005MXJYXO)" I could actually use my HDD as an external HDD.

With [this](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-7-to-usb-external-hard-drive-must-read/) tutorial I can install Windows 7 on a external HDD without losing data, and as my HDD has already Windows 8 installed...

**The question is**: Can I Install Windows 7 over my HDD with Windows 8, or boot my HDD with the box enclosure without losing data?

Current OS: Ubuntu 12.04 on USB device.

Comment: If you install Windows 8 over the Windows 7 installation then the Windows 7 installation is lost.  You can upgrade the installation then data won't be lost.

Comment: Nopes, i wanna do the opposite,
Install W7 over W8.

Comment: The answer is the same. If you install Windows 7 over Windows 8 then your data will be lose. So backup the data then do it.  You can apply that tutorial to Windows 8 or Windows 7 you just need a valid .vim file.

Comment: Then you're still not answering it, because i asked for a solution without losing all my data. Thanks btw, now i'm at least aware.

Comment: Actually...I did answer your question.  You just didn't like the answer.

Comment: I can't upvote your comment... And no you didn't. Btw, can you answer if i can or not boot my sata hdd with box?

Comment: I already answered the question twice.  I won't be posting an answer, since it will only be downvoted by serial downvoters in a month.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6774/discussion-between-ramhound-and-hyztname)